# Not able to group the selected data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I am a learner of database, i guess i am asking very basic question, please bear with me.

I wanted to fetch a list of values from a table. List of values will be ordered according to some criteria.

*Example:* I have a column named **courseOffered** in ***college*** table, where i am saving a string like: **java, c++, android etc**.

i have another two columns called **primarySubject** and **secondarySubject** in ***user*** table.

My first fetching logic is, according to **primarySubject**, row values of college table must be first priority in the list, then according to **secondarySubject**, row values of college table must be second priority in the list and rest values will be at last appended, which are unrelated to **primarySubject** or **secondarySubject**.

What so far i tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM test.college
WHERE Courses_Offered LIKE CONCAT('%',RTRIM((SELECT
                           Primary_Subject
                         FROM test.user
                         WHERE Email = 'r.veer7@gmail.com')),'%')
     OR Courses_Offered LIKE CONCAT('%',RTRIM((SELECT
                         Secondary_Subject
                           FROM test.user
                           WHERE Email = 'r.veer7@gmail.com')),'%')
     OR LOWER(Location)IN(SELECT
                LOWER(Location)
              FROM test.user
              WHERE Email = 'r.veer7@gmail.com')
```

the above query fetches all the data but not as i wanted above, its fetching as rows are saved in table, now i want a kind of grouping around every fetch in the above query, how should i do it?

Comment: use order by , and group by for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this you can use group by and order by

```
SELECT *
FROM test.college
WHERE Courses_Offered LIKE CONCAT('%',RTRIM((SELECT Primary_Subject FROM test.user WHERE Email = 'r.veer7@gmail.com')),'%')
     OR Courses_Offered LIKE CONCAT('%',RTRIM((SELECT Secondary_Subject FROM test.user WHERE Email = 'r.veer7@gmail.com')),'%')
     OR LOWER(Location)IN(SELECT LOWER(Location) FROM test.user WHERE Email = 'r.veer7@gmail.com')
GROUP by college.column_name
ORDER BY college.first_column_name ASC , college.second_column_name DESC
```